# How to write directive that hooks into ng-click handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm facing a situation in Angular where I sense I'm doing something wrong but I can't find the Angular way to solve it.

I'm developing a mobile app. I would like to create a directive let's call it `cc-tap-highlight` that would be used in conjunction with ng-click. Meaning that I could use it like this:

```
<a ng-click="doSomething()" cc-tap-highlight>Click me</a>
```

What this would do is to add a class to the clicked element and remove it after some seconds.

Now one could say, let's just manually bind to the elements `click` event in the directive. That would work for a desktop app. However, on mobile devices `Angular` does a lot of magic for us to have fast tap/clicks:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMobile/directive/ngClick.js

For sure, I don't want to reimplement all of it's magic!

So, currently, instead of having my `cc-tap-highlight` directive I use this rather hackish approach:

In the view

```
<a ng-click="doSomething($event)" cc-tap-highlight>Click me</a>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.doSomething = function($event){
    //do your things with $event.currentTarget
}
```

There are two major problems with this approach:

1. the controller should not manipulate the DOM
2. We need to repeat the patter over and over through our entire code base violating DRY

However, I can't for the life of me, figure out how to write a directive that hooks into the `ng-click` handler and does it's things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make your directive generate a ng-click directive with wrapper function.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/JhUXBOv2W4QYtknIbBlY?p=preview) a quick example. It's by far not thoroughly tested but I think the principle is sound. What you want is your custom code to run before/after the click event regardless of how that's triggered(tap,click, whatever).

*This does have the drawback that it creates a new scope so interaction with other directives that may need isolate scope was not tested.*

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('myClick', ['$parse','$compile', function($parse, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile : function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      //you can call the wrapper function whatever you want.
      //_myClick might be more appropriate to indicate it's not really public
      tElement.attr('ng-click', 'myClick($event)');
      tElement.removeAttr('my-click');
      var fn = $parse(tAttrs['myClick']);

      return {
        pre : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          console.log(scope, controller);
          scope.myClick = function(event) {
            console.log('myClick.before');
            fn(scope, {$event:event});
            console.log('myClick.after');
          };

          $compile(iElement)(scope);
        },
        post : function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {

        }
      };
    },
    scope : true
  };
}]);
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.test = function($event) {
    console.log('test', $event);
  };

  //this is to show that even if you have a function with the same name,
  //the wrapper function is still the one bound thanks to the new scope
  $scope.myClick = function() {
    console.log('dummy my click');
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="test($event)">NG-CLICK</button>
<button my-click="test($event)">MY-CLICK</button>
<button ng-click="myClick($event)">MY-CLICK-DUPLICATE-FN</button>
```

Comment: That will work but it's also a great pain since it would mean to replace `ng-click` with `my-click` everywhere where it's needed. I think the real fix needs to be made within the Angular framework itself. They should trigger a event directly on the element so that one can bind to that when writing directives. I created an issue and a PR but it needs more work.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3218